# HQL statement to use LIKE for each array value

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need to include like for each value of input array in HQL.

Example input array: `new String[]{"Value1%", "Value2%", "Value3%"}`

And my query should be like

```
id like "Value1%" or id like "Value2%" or id like "Value3%"
```

I tried as below

```
for(int inx=0;inx<Count;inx++){
            id+="id like id"+inx;
            if(inx!=Count-1){
                id+=" or ";
            }
        }
for(int inx=0;inx<Count;inx++){
            id = "id"+inx;
            qry.setParameter("id"+inx,Criteria[inx]);
        }
```

It was throwing me below error

> org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [id0]

I think it is expecting a variable to be given as parameter but I don't want to create more variables for each input value.

Comment: Normally a named parameter has represented by :param. Add : before the second id

Answer (score 0):

I've read your code and I've seen a possible error:

1. Named parameter starts with `:`

So your code can be replaced as follow:

Assignment of named parameter:

```
id+="id like :id"+inx;
```

Replacement of named parameter:

```
qry.setParameter(":id"+inx,Criteria[inx]);
```